# Recovering OST file without profile

Tags: exchange-2007, profile, exchange

We have a Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 and offer this solution to many customers.

Recently, a customer had his personal Exchange server crash (which is what made him our customer). He called some technician to see if he could repair his server before calling us, but this said tech wasn't able to do anything for them.

Now that all his mailbox are on our server, he would like to transfer his old emails over to the new profile, but the tech deleted all profiles on the client machines while trying to repair his Exchange server.

So my customer still has the OST files but they are not related to any profiles. Is there any way to re-attach them to a profile, or to convert them into PST files that he could then import into his new profile?

The only thing I found were third party software that could to the conversion, but I am wondering if Microsoft has any tools that could re-attach the OST to a new profile.

I have also tried the scanpst.exe and scanost.exe to no avail.

Thank you

Comment: What version of Outlook was the OST created with?

Comment: The OST was created with Outlook 2003.

Comment: More details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466716/reading-an-outlook-2003-ost-file

Comment: I'm completely impressed with this [OST to PST conversion tool](http://www.convertostpst.org/) which not only allowed me to recover all my important emails from my corrupt OST but also restored deleted emails as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this natively with Microsoft tools.  You will need to purchase an OST to PST converter.

OST's can only be opened on the machine they were created on, by the profile that created it.  That is why there are so many companies selling these OST converters.

Comment: Would you happen to be able to suggest a safe and good one, since we will probably end up purchasing a software of that nature for this issue and any future ones?

Comment: None that I have personally used.  Most are trialware, so you can play around to see if the tool fits the job, and more importantly your work flow.

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/kernel-ost-viewer/ is a free Viewer, and they have a $200 OST to PST converter.

Answer (score 1):

OST fles can not be reattached to any profile to recover an ost fiel you have to convert ost to pst file. As Microsoft does not provide any ost topst conversion tool, you have to go for third party **[convert ost to pst tool](http://www.convert-ost.net)** to convert ost file to pst file

Answer (score 1):

Exchange OST to PST recoverys your damaged or repair ost file recover into Outlook pst file with a short term of time. For more information http://download.cnet.com/Quick-Recovery-for-MS-Exchange-OST-MS-Outlook-PST/3000-2367_4-75532430.html

Answer (score 0):

There is some useful information here and some utilities under "See Also", although the utility that would probably help you the most, libpff, has to be compiled.

http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Personal_Folder_File_(PAB,_PST,_OST)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your useful feedback. We decided to purchase the Kernel OST Recovery software from http://www.convertost.com/ and it seems to work fine, recovered 6 OST up to now and got everything I needed, and it is very simple to use. So if ever anyone is having the same problem, it might be an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I had zero problems with [this one](http://www.recoverytoolbox.com/outlook.html).  It may not be the most polished, but it worked flawlessly for a decent price.